# Using timers in ARM embedded C programming

Tags: c, timer, operating-system, embedded

I'm writing a pong-type game in C, which will run on an ARM board over an LCD screen. Part of the requirements for the game is something called 'magic time'.

A "magic time" period occurs at random intervals between 5 and 10 seconds - i.e, between 5 and 10 seconds after the last "magic time" period, and lasts for a random duration of 2 to 10 seconds.

Comment: What's the purpose of `magicTime == magicTimeLength;`? It compares a boolean with an integer (which itself is a problem), but doesn't store the result anywhere.

Comment: This is a question and answer site. You ask questions, we answer them. What is your question?

Comment: Timers are not part of the ARM core (except ARM Cortex-M SYSCLK, but that is not Cortex-M code).  Peripheral devices in ARM based microcontrollers are vendor defined. You need to specify precisely what ARM part from what vendor.  You could probably simplify the entire system by using an RTOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your question (do you execute this code every second via timer interrupt, or?), but there are some errors that I see on the first sight:

```
while (magicTime == true) {
    magicTimeLength++;
    magicTime == magicTimeLength;
}
```

Last line (`magicTime == magicTimeLength;`) don't do anything - it simply evaluates if `magicTime` is equal to the `magicTimeLength`, so you will enter dead-loop.

I think that you want to do this:

1. Init `magicTimeOccurence` with random value within 5 and 10.
2. Init `magicTimeLength` with random value within 2 and 10.
3. Every second, if `magicTimeOccurence` is greater than 0, decrease
   its value by one.
4. Once `magicTimeOccurence` hits 0, decrease `magicTimeLength` value
   by one.
5. Check if `magicTimeLength` is greater than 0. If it is, it is magic
   time period (so, set the `magicTime` flag to `true`). Decrement
   `magicTimeLength`.
6. If  `magicTimeLength`, set `magicTime` to `false` and go to step 1.

You should initialize your `timer0` interrupt with period of 1s. I think that you accomplished it with

```
/* Set timer 0 period */
T0PR = 0;
T0MR0 = SYS_GetFpclk(TIMER0_PCLK_OFFSET)/(TIMER0_TICK_PER_SEC);
```

but make sure that is triggered every second.

Here is sample code, it should show you what I mean.

```
/* In     void InitTimer0Interrupt() */

...
T0TCR_bit.CE = 1;     /* Counting Enable */

magicTimeOccurence = 5+(rand()%5);
magicTimeLength = 2+(rand()%8);
magicTime = false;

    __enable_interrupt();
}

/* In     void Timer0IntrHandler (void) */

void Timer0IntrHandler (void) {


    /* clear interrupt */
    T0IR_bit.MR0INT = 1;
    VICADDRESS = 0;
    if(magicTimeOccurence > 0)
    {
        magicTimeOccurence--;
    }
    else if(magicTimeLength > 0){
        magicTime = true;
        magicTimeLenght--;
    }
    else{
        magicTime = false;
        magicTimeOccurence = 5+(rand()%5);
        magicTimeLength = 2+(rand()%8);
    }

     /* take action on timer interrupt */
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's executed every second using a timerinterrupt in the main class.
I've just realized how flawed my logic was, I've been trying to set a boolean's value to the length of the time. 
Thank you for trying to answer, I'll rewrite my code and reply.

Comment: No problems, good luck! I added sample code in my answer, so you could check it.

Comment: Would this work? I was under the impression i'd have to call a while loop so that it would keep incrementing / decreasing in value?
Or will it keep running the if statements due to the timerinterrupt ?

Comment: and wouldn't that set magicTime to true even if magicTimeOccurence is greater than 0 "    if(magicTimeOccurence > 0)
    {
        magicTimeOccurence--;
    }
    else if(magicTimeLength > 0){
        magicTime = true;
        magicTimeLenght--;
"

Comment: Timer interrupt calls this function every 1s. So, every second one of variables (magicTimeOccurence or magicTimeLength) will be decremented. If you decrement magicTimeOccurence, magicTime is set to false. Once magicTimeOccurence reach 0, you will decrement magicTime and magicTime will be set to true.

Comment: No, it will not. It will enter second or third branch only if magicTimeOccurence is equal to 0, because of that else in front of if.